# Trouble Download Visual Studio 2017 Community

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Whenever I click on the .exe file, bootstrapper comes up, loads for a couple of seconds, and disappears.  I have tried running install cleanup and making sure that Windows is up-to-date.  I have looked around and Googled and absolutely cannot find an answer to this problem.  It is a Windows 10 personal laptop.  If I need to provide additional information, please let me know what I should provide and I'll be glad to do so.  I appreciate any help!

Here is the log:

```
[9/5/2019, 14:39:30] === Logging started: 2019/09/05 14:39:30 ===
[9/5/2019, 14:39:30] Executable: C:\Users\cshet\Desktop\vs_community__914888294.1537592452__rid.30012.exe v16.2.29215.179
[9/5/2019, 14:39:30] --- logging level: standard ---
[9/5/2019, 14:39:30] Directory 'C:\Users\cshet\AppData\Local\Temp\ecbf740fd1fcd9a45f27ddd0d1\' has been selected for file extraction
[9/5/2019, 14:39:30] Extracting files to: C:\Users\cshet\AppData\Local\Temp\ecbf740fd1fcd9a45f27ddd0d1\
[9/5/2019, 14:39:30] Extraction took 250 milliseconds
[9/5/2019, 14:39:30] Executing extracted package: 'vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe ' with commandline '  --env "_SFX_CAB_EXE_PACKAGE:C:\Users\cshet\Desktop\vs_community__914888294.1537592452__rid.30012.exe _SFX_CAB_EXE_ORIGINALWORKINGDIR:C:\Users\cshet\Desktop"'
[9/5/2019, 14:39:37] The entire Box execution exiting with result code: 0x0
[9/5/2019, 14:39:37] Launched extracted application exiting with result code: 0x1389
[9/5/2019, 14:39:37] === Logging stopped: 2019/09/05 14:39:37 ===
```

Comment: As Microsoft currently only publishes Visual Studio 2019, where did you get the VS2017 installation? Your problem might be that the downloader can no longer find the older Microsoft files.

Comment: I don't think it's specific to the version because I've tried 2019 too, so I decided to try 2017 after that.  Sorry, I should have mentioned that.  I'm going to include my log file for reference on the error I am getting.

Comment: I just tried downloading 2019 Community again and the log pretty much looks the same.

Comment: @OliviaShettles - Is the machine in question a personal or company machine? Most Visual Studio 2017+ installations problems are caused only two possible reasons.  The first is a certificate error, this is typically the case where, the certificate that was used to signed the installer is not trusted.  The second is the fact the installer is unable to make the required connections to download the data.  Both of these issues are typically only found in a corporate environment.  You don't indicate what OS you are using, which might be important, so please include that information in an edit.

Comment: Sure, I'll include that above.  It's a personal computer, Windows 10.

Comment: It's seriously so frustrating.  I don't know what could be the problem.

Comment: Where did you get the Visual Studio Community boot loader exactly?  Can you verify the root certificate authority used to signed the executable is in your certificate store?  Are you able complete [step 1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) as explained on that page?

Comment: Sure, I am getting it from here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/
The .exe file downloads, but when I click it, it brings up the loader and then disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Some advice, to be done point-by-point, not all-together
(of which you already did some):

- Try to download the installation again.
- Assure you have enough disk space and Windows is up-to-date
  and your computer fulfills the requirements for Visual Studio
- Temporarily disable any antivirus software
- Clean up the `%temp%` folder, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\`
  and any other files/folders created by the installer
- Run the installer as administrator
- Boot in Safe Mode with Networking mode
- If you have Electron installed there might be a conflict with the
  `NODE_OPTIONS` environmental variable that needs to be disabled
  (see [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/224084/installer-wont-show-up-when-i-have-node-options-va.html))

Comment: I have not tried booting in safe mode yet, so that will be my next step.

Comment: I tried all of these and none of them worked.  I'm sorry.